# Windows' "color a", "color b" equivalent on bash terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

On Windows OS, I can type just `color a` or `color b` or `color c` etc. to change the font color in the terminal temporarily.

Is there a command to do this in bash terminal?

I don't want to make permanent changes, just for the open session is enough.

Answer (score 6):

You're referring to a [command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/color) that expects values 0-f (i.e., 0 through 15 decimal).  The analogous command would use [**`tput`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html):

```
tput setaf 10
```

("a" is hexdecimal for 10), for the *foreground* color and

```
tput setab 10
```

for the *background* color.  Those are separate [*terminfo*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Color-Handling) capabilities.

That example assumes your terminal description has at least 16 colors.  If it has only 8, `tput` will not notice, but the result will be unsatisfactory.  You can see this by

```
tput colors
```

By default, `tput` uses the current value of `$TERM` to select a terminal description.  You can override this with the `-T` option.  For example, if you are using **`xterm`** (as opposed to some other terminal which sets `TERM` to "xterm"), you could use the `xterm-16color` terminal description as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

(You can probably see that the `tput` on line 15 had no useful effect, which is expected since **`10`** is outside the range of 8 colors).

The terminal description, whether [`xterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm) or [`xterm-16color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-16color) (or [`xterm-256color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-256color)) tells `tput` how to make an escape sequence which can be written to the terminal.  Your bash prompt may send escape sequences as well, setting or resetting colors.  If you called `tput` and echoed text within a shell script, you might see the colored text while the same commands (separated by bash prompts) might not behave the same way.  Also, some programs (such as `ls`) set/reset colors.  There is only one terminal's color-state to share with these different applications; terminals don't automatically switch between them.

Testing a shell script is more predictable than relying on details of your shell prompt.  Here is an example

```
#!/bin/sh
case $TERM in
xterm*)
        TERM=xterm-256color
        ;;
linux*)
        TERM=linux-16color
        ;;
esac
export TERM
for p in $(seq 0 15)
do
        tput setab $p
        for q in $(seq 0 15)
        do
                tput setaf $q
                printf '%x%x' $p $q
        done
        tput sgr0
        printf '\n'
done
```

and a screenshot in xterm:

[image]

Comment: actually, I have tried these ones but either they did not work or I could not understand exactly.

Comment: @muyustan or something else might be interfering (say, you have a coloured prompt which resets the colours)

Comment: This is not the analogous command, because this is not what the `color` command does.  To do what the `color` command does, one would need a DECCARA that could change colours (as some terminal emulators support as an extension), and a way to describe that via terminfo.  The `color` command _both_ sets the current pen/paper colours _and_ changes the colours of all existing cells in the screen buffer.

Comment: @JdeBP actually, if it would be able to change the lines which comes next, it would be enough. However, even that is not satisfied in my situation. I am adding what my terminal looks like when I use the commands in this answer. See my comment below

Comment: I am adding how my terminal(default of Linux Mint 19.03) responds: https://ibb.co/g98D2j5 --  It looks like, `setaf` does not do anything and `setab` does not do exactly what your example shows.